# How to access "Id" in vue.js script

Tags: html, vue.js

I am trying to access this id="cm_count" in vue.js script by using "this.$refs.cm_count.innerText" but i am unable to get the required out put. So i am struggling how to solve the issue. If i am doing wrong please let me know how to access this "Id" and css in vue.js script
**html**

```
<span id="cm_count" ref="cm_count">
    ({{ c_count }})
</span>
```

Is this a right way to access id "cm_count "in vue.js and also need .css in vue.js script
**vue.js**

```
this.$refs.cm_count.innerText ='('+ count +')';
this.$refs.cm_count.css('color', '#DB0038');
```

Comment: The title of your question does not reflect what you wrote.

Comment: You're doing Vue backwards. You should put values into the template using the `{{ }}` interpolation and such, and that will automatically reflect when the component's data changes. It's a bad idea to manipulate the DOM from the component as if you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, we select item and manipulate it. In Vue, we say items how it should react some changes and let everything run. In rare cases, selecting an object and changing its state can be necessary, but in your case, you should use computed property:

```
<span id="cm_count" ref="cm_count" :syle="spanStyles">
    ({{ c_count }})
</span>


computed: {
  spanStyles() {
    return `color:${this.c_count > 5 ? 'red' : 'black'}`;
  }
}
```

UPDATE AFTER COMMENT

Buttons don't have href attribute. That's why I assume you have a link.

```
<a href="linkTo" @click="doSomething">...</a>


data() {
  return {
    isButtonClicked: false
  }
},
methods: {
  doSomething() {
    // you don't need to set a timeout here,
    // but if it goes to the wrong link,
    // you can use it to delay the changing of the link.
    setTimeout(() => this.isButtonClicked = !this.isButtonClicked, 10
  }
},
computed: {
  linkTo() {
    return this.isButtonClicked ? 'link1.com' : link2.com;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bulent. Solution has helped me. And one more question I have to use this "this.$refs.liked_cm.attr('href', '/post_comment_like_remove/' + catid);". While we click on button I want to change that link with this href